# Azure Pipelines status badge not showing

Tags: azure, devops

Enabled anonymous access by checking off **Organization settings > Pipeline > Settings > Disable anonymous access to badges**

Any badge we copy to display the pipeline build status display as the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcBMb.png

I discover that users authenticated to the Azure DevOps environment have access to the badge and non-authenticated users (incognito browser) do not. Enabling the following setting doesn't change this situation:

**- Organization settings > Policies > External guest access**